# eclipse exception thrown

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

Here is the thrown exception:

```
    SEVERE: Error loading WebappClassLoader
    delegate: false
    repositories:
       /WEB-INF/classes/
      ----------> Parent Classloader:
      org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@3d434234
      controlador.GeraSequenciaServlet
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: controlador.GeraSequenciaServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1516)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1361)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1095)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:809)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:865)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
    25/08/2011 12:26:59 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
    +++++++++++++++++++
```

I have already checked web.xml, and the GeraSequenciaServlet is there...so I became lost...

BTW: I am using Eclipse IDE, in a Linux Fedora 14, Phenom processor, 4GB RAM.

Answer (score 3):

Your classes should go to `WEB-INF/classes`. If you are using eclipse WTP server deployment, then you should go to `Right click > Properties > Facets`, and enable "Dynamic Web Project".

Comment: Ty,for you answer. There is something strange. I have already enabled the Dynamic Web Project. I have seen the .metadata/.plugins/...wetwebapps/.../WEB-INF/classes, and the servlet is not there...I cant understand why.

Comment: the .java file should be in src/, and should be compiled.

Comment: Oh, yes, it is. Path is JavaResources/src/controlador/GeraSequenciaServlet.java. I cant figure out why it is not compiled. all other servlets are compiled, this one, needs Jena library to. I have already inserted Jena lib at WebContent/lib.

Comment: Ok,class was compiled, I inserted the missing Jena Library at server path and the class was compiled. Thank you once more Bozho.